# how to find multiple regex patterns in a single way using Perl

Tags: perl

## Question Updated

I have list of (few more) regex patterns like: (***Note:*** Sequence is very Important)

```
([a-z]+)(\d+)
\}([a-z]+)
([a-z]+)(\+|\-)
([0-9])\](\+|\-)
...
...
```

my input file like :

```
\ce{CO2}  
\ce{2CO}  
\ce{H2O}  
\ce{Sb2O3}  
...
...
```

In my code I am finding the each and every regex patterns like

```
if($string=~m/([a-z]+)(\d+)/g) {  my statements ... }
if($string=~m/\}([a-z]+)/g) {  my statements ... }
if($string=~m/([a-z]+)(\+|\-)/g) {  my statements ... }
if($string=~m/([0-9])\](\+|\-)/g) {  my statements ... }
```

Instead of doing the above code Is there any other way to simplify the code?

Could you someone please share your thoughts for my improvement for better coding.

Comment: Please provide a source if you are quoting something.

Comment: Could you use alternatives like `if ( $string =~ /$regex1|$regex2|.../g ) { ... }` ?

Comment: I've downvoted because I think your question is very hard to read. I think you are using quote markup for your regular text, but it could also be that you are quoting something. I have written an answer for what I believe you want to do, but I could be entirely wrong. Please [edit] your question and reformat it. Use normal text for text, code markup for code and only use quotes if you actually quote something, and in that case provide a link to what you are quoting. Thanks.

Comment: @ssr1012: You are often unreasonably agitated about getting anonymous/close votes when your questions clearly deserve them. You are unlikely to get related feedback: there is a reason for the votes being anonymous. Please just spend more effort on writing good and clear English and explaining yourself better, then you will see the votes go down. And your questions will always be much better received if you show the code that you have written in attempting to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Your regexes use parentheses `()` but it is not clear whether you are using them to capture parts of the match results or just for grouping.  If you need capturing then @simbabque answer looks like the way to go.  Are you just using parens to group?  If so then there are easier ways to match multiple regex.

Comment: @Borodin: I am really worried about the way of asking the question since I understood that I have clearly explained what are all my issues/request/requirements however you are all people expecting further more details on my question. Anyhow I will try to update myself upmost level.

Comment: Requested question are updated.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: Your question is very hard to read, so this is pretty much guesswork. I am not sure I understand what you want to do.

When you are processing data in a dynamic way, a typical approach is to use a [*dispatch table*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispatch_table). We can do something similar here. Often a hash or hash reference is used for that, but since we want a specific order, I will be using an array instead.

```
my @dispatch = (
    {
        pattern => qr/f(o)(o)/,
        callback => sub {
            my ($one, $two) = @_;
            print "Found $one and $two\n";
        },
    },
    {
        pattern => qr/(bar)/,
        callback => sub {
            my $capture = shift;
            print "Saw $capture";
        },
    },
);
```

This basically is a list of search patterns and associated instructions. Each pattern has a [*callback*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)), which is a code reference. I decided it would make sense to pass in the capture variables, because your patterns have capture groups.

Now in order to call them, we iterate over the dispatch array, match the pattern and then call the associated callback, passing in all the captures.

```
my $text = "Foo bar foo bar baz.";

foreach my $search (@dispatch) {
    if ($text =~ $search->{pattern}) {
        $search->{callback}->(@{^CAPTURE}); # this requires Perl 5.26
    }
}
```

Please note that I am using [`@{^CAPTURE}`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40%7B%5ECAPTURE%7D), which was added to Perl in version 5.25.7, so you would require at least [the stable Perl 5.26 release](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5260delta.html#%40%7B%5ECAPTURE%7D%2C-%25%7B%5ECAPTURE%7D%2C-and-%25%7B%5ECAPTURE_ALL%7D) to use it. (On an older Perl, `my @capture = $t =~ $search->{pattern}` and `$search->{callback}->(@capture)` will behave similarly).

This is way more elegant than having a list of `if () {}` statement because it's very easy to extend. The dispatch table could be created on the fly, based on some input, or entirely read from disk.

When we run this code, it creates the following output

```
Found o and o
Saw bar
```

This is not very spectacular, but you should be able to adapt it to your patterns. On the other hand I don't know what you are actually trying to do. If you wanted to modify the string instead of only matching, you might need additional arguments for your callbacks.

If you want to learn more about dispatch tables, I suggest you read the second chapter of [Mark Jason Dominus' excellent book *Higher Order Perl*](https://hop.perl.plover.com/), which is available for free as a PDF on his website.

Comment: If you don't have a recent Perl `if (my @capture = $t =~ $search->{pattern}) { $search->{callback}->(@capture); }` will DRT.

Comment: @mr_ron thanks, I incorporated your suggestion into my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is hard to read, mainly because you have the /g at the end of your regex searches (which returns a list), however, you only check if it matches once.

I'm making the following assumptions

- All matches are required
- the code can be a single or double match
- both groups captured in one line

i think you want

```
while ( $string =~ /(([a-z]+)(\d+)|\}([a-z]+)|([a-z]+)(\+|\-)|([0-9])\](\+|\-))/g )
{
#$1 has the whole match
#$2 has the first group if defined
#$3 has the second group if defined
}
```

However, I prefer the method below. this will capture in one line

```
while ($string =~ /([a-z]+\d+|\}[a-z]+|[a-z]+\+|\-|[0-9]\]\+|\-)/g ) 
{
# in here split the match if required
}
```

I recommend you use [regex comments](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Details-on-some-modifiers) to make this clearer.

if you just want a single match, use

```
if(
$string=~m/([a-z]+)(\d+)/   ||
$string=~m/\}([a-z]+)/      ||
$string=~m/([a-z]+)(\+|\-)/ ||
$string=~m/([0-9])\](\+|\-)/ 
)
{
#some code
}
```